# When using a Caesar decrypting program, a lot of "U"'s get output. C#

Tags: c#, encryption, caesar-cipher

```
using System;

class Decrypter 
{
static void Main ( string [] args )
{ 
    //The encrypted data is read from a file to a string, this 
    string encryptedData = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\TomTower\Desktop\Programming and Data Structures\Assessment 1\EncryptedText.txt");
    char[] alphabet = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};

    // The code is supposed to take every character in an input string and left shift them back a 5 places. Y becomes T. B becomes W
    foreach(char c in encryptedData)
    {
        if (c == ' ')
            Console.Write(" ");
            else
            {
                int charPosition = 0;

                charPosition = Array.IndexOf(alphabet, c);

                charPosition = charPosition - 5;

                if (charPosition < 0)
                {    
                charPosition = charPosition + 26;
                }
                else;
                {
                Console.Write(alphabet[charPosition]);
                }
            };
```

The input data is as follows: 
YMJNS HWJIN GQJQJ LFHDT
KYMJR FYMJR FYNHF QLJSN
ZXLJT WLJGT TQJBN QQGJJ
CUQTW JINSF KWJJU ZGQNH
YFQPN SMNXM TRJHN YDTKQ
NSHTQ STSYM JGNHJ SYJSF
WDTKM NXGNW YMXYT UGTTQ
JBFXG TWSTS YMJXJ HTSIT
KSTAJ RGJWJ NLMYJ JSKNK
YJJSN SYTRT IJXYK FRNQD
HNWHZ RXYFS HJXYM JXTST
KFXMT JRFPJ WXYTU QFWLJ
QDXJQ KYFZL MYMJB JSYTS
YTGJH TRJTS JTKYM JBTWQ
I’XKN SJXYR FYMJR FYNHN
FSXBM TXJBT WPSTB KTWRX
YMJGF XNXTK HTRUZ YJWXH
NJSHJ FSIJQ JHYWT SNHHN
WHZNY WDXYT UMJQF NIYMJ
KTZSI FYNTS XTKYM JINLN
YFQJW FFSIN XBNIJ QDWJH
TLSNX JIFXY MJKTW JKFYM
JWTKY MJINL NYFQF LJXYT
UGTTQ JFSFQ LJGWF NXSTB
FKZSI FRJSY FQFXU JHYTK
RTIJW SRFYM JRFYN HXFSI
TAJWY MJQFX YHJSY ZWDBF
XZXJI YTKTW RYMJY MJTWJ
YNHFQ KTZSI FYNTS TKRTI
JWSHT RUZYJ WXHNJ SHJJS
I

and my output looks like this:
http://puu.sh/layx0/27e50b70a9.png

Comment: using the same code, I don't get the extra U's...

Comment: Same as @DrewJordan but some things are odd in the code : `else;` and `};` (and on a side note you can use a string for alphabet it supports IndexOf and indexing like a char array see [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mxq5y7))

Answer (score 1):

If the text in your file has non matching data in it your Array.IndexOf will return a -1.  When you then adjust by adding 26 to it the output is a 'U'.

Safeguard for bad data:

```
    foreach (char c in encryptedData)
    {
        if (c == ' ')
        {
            Console.Write(" ");
        }
        else
        {
            int charPosition = 0;

            charPosition = Array.IndexOf(alphabet, c);

            if (charPosition == -1)
            {//Check for non expected items
                Console.Write("*");
            }
            else
            {
                charPosition = charPosition - 5;

                if (charPosition < 0)
                {
                    charPosition = charPosition + 26;
                }
                Console.Write(alphabet[charPosition]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe not sure without the original file

Comment: I'm 100% sure it's CRLF now. looking at the output, `UU` occurs after every 4 'blocks' (once for CR and once for LF).

Comment: Could be simpler to replace the if/else by first doing the IndexOf and if it's -1 just print the initial char as-is (or some default char) ; that would take care of the space case or any char not in alphabet

Comment: So i could add a line of code after "if(charposition == -1)" with Console.Write("") to just make it write nothing?